# What does RUNNING in ifconfig output mean?

Tags: solaris, ifconfig

Does anyone know what the RUNNING flag in ifconfig output means? (I don't know that it matters much, but this is on a Solaris 10 box.)

The only thing I've been able to find on it so far is [this forum post](http://www.unix.com/ip-networking/79827-solaris-9-new-plumbed-interface-will-not-enter-running-state.html).

Even assuming that's accurate, I'd greatly appreciate a more technical explanation, as well as instructions on how to change the RUNNING state of an interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The running state is typically associated with the UP state of the interface, i.e. is the interface turned on, and is there a link over that interface (ip address, etc)

A good way to word it:

> RUNNING

```
     Indicates that the required resources for  an  interface
     are  allocated.  For some interfaces this also indicates
     that the link is up.
```

One way to change the running state is to stop it, i.e. `down` the interface.

Full page [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5166/ifconfig-1m/index.html)

Comment: This isnt true, on solaris, if you down an interface it wont effect the running state.

Answer (score 3):

It means there is a network link to a switch, ie its plugged in.

Comment: The selected answer is **incomplete** and **incorrect** without this answer.